# Coverage of Quantum Electrodynamics (QED) in introductory Quantum Field Theory (QFT) books

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, quantum-electrodynamics

Which QFT books also cover QED? I am not very familiar with QED, so I am looking for QFT books which cover QED too (I know they cover Quantum Chromodynamics (QCD).).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it usually is. I would not say that introductory courses teach you much about QCD, rather they start with scalar fields and QED.

As the bosonic part of QED is based on a simpler gauge theory than the [Yang-Mills theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory) for QCD, you actually want to learn QED first. (There is only the one-dimensional Lie-Group U(1) <=> one photon, SU(3) <=> 8 gluons)

Comment: So I should learn QED first?

Comment: @War: In the very most cases yes (as I wrote in the answer above, didn't I?). Right now I don't see anything that is more complicated in QED than it would be in QCD. In any case, the Feynman diagrams are simpler.